# Linux Kernel: strncpy_from_user() copying too many bytes

Tags: c, linux, string, kernel

I'm trying to write a character device, and I'm copying from user to kernel space using `strncpy_from_user`. However, it almost always copies too much data. The way I'm doing it is:

```
//len is buffer length.
tmp = (struct msg_list *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct msg_list),GFP_ATOMIC);
tmp->msg = (char*)kmalloc(len,GFP_ATOMIC);

strncpy_from_user(tmp->msg,buff,len);
```

Buffer length generally outputs 1+characters seen, which I assume is because it is counting in the trailing NUL.

e.g. The following has buffer length 4:

```
echo 123 > /dev/my_chardev
```

`strcnpy_from_user`, however, might copy way over 4 Bytes.
According to the documentation, the last parameter is "The maximum numbers of bytes to copy". But this does not seem to be true.

I tried manually setting `(temp->msg)[len-1] = 0`, but this seems to cause problems (infinite loops and segfaults). What is the best way to safely copy a string from user to kernel space?

#### EDIT:

As Matteo mentioned in the comments, `echo` writes a `\n` by default, he also pointed out that a trailing `NUL` does indeed mean nothing to `read/write` syscalls. This is the solution that worked for me:

```
tmp = (struct msg_list *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct msg_list),GFP_ATOMIC);
tmp->msg = (char*)kmalloc(len+1,GFP_ATOMIC);

strncpy_from_user(tmp->msg,buff,len);

(tmp->msg)[len]=0;
```

Comment: "But this does not seem to be true". How are you coming to this conclusion?

Comment: Because it copies more than `len` characters.

Comment: But how are you coming to the conclusion? Did you check the return value of `strncpy_from_user`? Did you dump the contents of `tmp->msg`? And what is `len` set to?

Comment: I must admit that I'm not sure. If I try to `printk` it, or `strlen` it, the lack of a trailing `NUL` would make it fail anyway.

Maybe it does copy exactly `len` characters, but `echo` doesn't produce a string with a trailing `NUL`.

Comment: How are you setting `len`?

Comment: it is set automatically by the read system call. Whenever someone attempts to access the character device file, it calls that function with the parameters. EDIT: I mean write.

Comment: I suspect it's actually the `echo` call. Maybe instead of a `NUL`, it has a trailing `\n`. I might have to allocate 1 more char in `tmp->msg` and set that to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the regular `strncpy`, the function you are using does not terminate the buffer if the string is as long as the maximum length you specified (or longer). If `len` counts the number of actual characters written to the device and you want to put them in a C string,  you have to remember to add 1 in the allocation size and set the last byte to 0, otherwise you are going to have a non-terminated string around.

But *please*, if you are still struggling with C strings basics and NULL terminated vs counted strings stay away from kernel mode, if you want to play with virtual filesystems use FUSE.

Comment: Indeed. I thought `len` already included the trailing `NUL`, since it is set automatically through a system call. It seems the extra char is in fact a `\n`, maybe because I need to hit enter each time I run the `echo` command.

Comment: @laifs: that string is not going to be terminated, it's a *counted* string, and it cannot be otherwise, since `read` and `write` work with arbitrary data, where NUL has no particular meaning (i.e. data written to file can have embedded NULs, a NUL after all is just a regular byte). The newline is written explicitly by `echo`, to avoid it you should use `echo -n`.

Comment: ah, I see, thanks. I didn't know `echo` wrote new lines. It does make sense that `read` and `write` wouldn't care about `NUL`.